# Mvvm nested propertychanged in model

Tags: c#, mvvm, model, nested, inotifypropertychanged

I use model class A that contains a list of model class B. Each of the models (A and B) implement the INotifyPropertyChanged and the events are fired correctly when a propertey changes. Model A has subscribed to this event from models B and if one occurs model A fires another property changed.

My problem is that I want to listen to changes within model A (including nestend model properties) in a service class which should write the changes to a database. But when model A fires propertychanged, in my service class I cannot know if the property that has changed belongs to model A or to one of the models B.

```
public class Model B : ObservableObject
{
...
  public int Property1
  {
    get{return property1;}
    set{ this.property1 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Property1");  
       }
  }
} 


public class ModelA : ObservableObject
{
 ...
 ObservableCollection<ModelB> modelsB;
 ...

 public ObservableCollection<ModelB> ModelsB
 {
   get
   {
     if(modelsB == null)
     {
       this.modelsB = new ObservableCollection<ModelB>();
       this.modelsB.CollectionChanged+= ModelBListChanged;
     }
     return modelsB;
   }
 }


  private int property2;
  public int Property2
  {
    get{return property2;}
    set{ this.property2 = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("Property2");  
       }
  }

 private void ModelBListChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
 {
    if(e.NewItems != null)
      {
        foreach(ObservableObject item in e.NewItems)
        {
          item.PropertyChanged += NotifyPropertyChanged;
        }
      }
      if (e.OldItems != null)
      {
        foreach (ObservableObject item in e.OldItems)
        {
          item.PropertyChanged -= NotifyPropertyChanged;
        }
      }
 }

 ...

}


public class SomeService
{
   ...

  ObservableCollection<ModelA> modelsA;

  public ObservableCollection<ModelA> ModelsA
  {
     get
     {
       if(modelsA == null)
       {
         modelsA = new ObservableCollection<ModelA>();

             //fill with data...
         ....
         foreach(...)
         {
        ModelB mb = new ModelB();
            //fill mb ...
        ...

        mb.PropertyChanged += ModelBChanged;
        modelsA.ModelsB.Add(mb);
         }
         ....
         modelsA.PropertyChanged += ModelsAChanged;
       }
       return modelsA;
     }
  }

  ...

  private void ModelsAChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    // determine the property that has changed and call the correct
    // update function for this property to write the data to database.

var ma = (ModelA) sender;

      switch(args.PropertyName)
      {
     ...
        case ModelA.Property1:
          //update database with function for property 1
          break;
        case ModelA.Property2:
          //update database with function for property 2
          break;
     ...
      }
  }

  private void ModelBChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
  {
    // How do I know to which ModelA this ModelB sender belongs?

var mb = (ModelB) sender;
switch(args.PropertyName)
      {
     ...
        case ModelB.Property1:
          //update database with function for property 1 of model B
          break;
       ...
      }
  }
}
```

How could this be solved?

Regards,

tabina

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your current code even compiles? You are turning a `CollectionChanged` event from your B collection into a `PropertyChanged` event on your A class, but you are referencing `PropertyName` which doesn't exist in a `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`.

Even if you could get that to work, it makes little sense since `CollectionChanged` events can reference multiple items, whereas `PropertyChanged` only ever references one.

Your B collection is already a public property of A. Why can't you subscribe directly to the changes in your service? eg.

```
public class SomeService
{
    ObservableCollection<ModelA> modelsA;

    public ObservableCollection<ModelA> ModelsA
    {
        get
        {
            if(modelsA == null)
            {
               modelsA = new ObservableCollection<ModelA>();
               //fill with data...

               modelsA.CollectionChanged += ModelsAChanged;

               foreach (ModelA A in modelsA)
                   A.ModelsB.CollectionChanged += ModelsBChanged;
            }

            return modelsA;
        }
    }

    private void ModelsAChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //remember to subscribe to ModelsB in any new ModelA instance that get added 
        //to the modelsA collection too, and unsubscribe when they get removed.
    }

    private void ModelsBChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. It should be the PropertyChangedEvent not CollectionChanged. I mixed it up typing this post.